# Build TransformBlocks from several functions of a class in DataFlow TPL

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I've been struggling with this problem for a few days now and I suspect I'm missing something or have misunderstood.

I have a class "Calculation" that has a function "StartCalculation". There are several steps in this function:

```
CreateResultsPath();
SetupLogger();
var solverHandler = new SolverHandler(this);
solverHandler.ProgressReporter += ProgressChanged;
solverHandler.RunSolver(); //should check solver was successful 
_optimizationResults = solverHandler.GetOptimizationResults();
WriteResultsFile(_optimizationResults);
WriteResultsToExcel(_optimizationResults);
```

Currently I start it with DataFlow in which I create only one Action Block:

```
ActionBlock< Calculation> optimiaztionBlock = new ActionBlock< Calculation>(_ => _. StartCalculation(),
            new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4, // number of cores from globals
                CancellationToken = _cancelationCancellationTokenSource.Token
            });
foreach (var calc in Calculations)
        {
            await optimiaztionBlock.SendAsync(calc);
        }
```

All this works, but I want to split the individual functions into the Transform blocks

Block 1:

```
CreateResultsPath();
SetupLogger();
```

Block 2:

```
var solverHandler = new SolverHandler(this);
solverHandler.ProgressReporter += ProgressChanged;
```

Block 3:

```
solverHandler.RunSolver(); //should check solver was successful 
_optimizationResults = solverHandler.GetOptimizationResults();
```

Block 4:

```
WriteResultsFile(_optimizationResults);
```

Block 5:

```
WriteResultsToExcel(_optimizationResults);
```

So far I am failing how to define the individual blocks so that I can also link them to each other.
I have tried to create a new class (e.x. OptimizationBuilder) that splits this into individual functions:

```
public Calculation InitCalculation(Calculation calc)
    {
        calc.CreateResultsPath();
        calc.SetupLogger();
        return calc;
    }
public SolverHandler Prepare Calculation (Calculation calc)
    {
        var solverHandler = new SolverHandler(calc); //refactor init and build phase
        return solverHandler;
    }
public OptimizationResults? RunSolver(SolverHandler solverHandler)
    {
        solverHandler.RunSolver(); //should check solver was successful 
        var results = solverHandler.GetOptimizationResults();
        return results;
    }
public void WriteResults(OptimizationResults results, Calculation calc)
    {
        calc.WritePartialFiles(results);
    }
```

Here I am again confronted with the problem of how to implement it in DataFlow.
my wish would be to create a block for individual functions and then link them to each other